# Animating the font size in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, fonts, scale

It seems like the font-size is animatable in SwiftUI now. However, when I animate it, I get a weird bounce effect: Not only is the font size animated, but the position of the text as well (that I never changed). What is going wrong here and how can I fix this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var big = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            big.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.system(size: big ? 100 : 20, weight: .bold))
                .animation(.spring(duration: 2, bounce: 0), value: big)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Text bounces around]

To better understand what's going on, I added a yellow background to the `Text` view. Curiously, the background is moving as expected: It scales up from the center as I would expect. However, the text inside seems to be anchored in the upper-left or lower-right corner respectively and I don't understand why it's doing that.

[image: Background moves differently]

I have also tried to use a custom animatable font modifier as suggested in [here](https://swdevnotes.com/swift/2021/animate-text-size-change-in-swiftui/#:%7E:text=SwiftUI%20does%20not%20provide%20a,use%20in%20your%20application%20code.). This is *slightly* better, but has similar issues. (What's peculiar though is that it doesn't seem to be deterministic: Sometimes it animates correctly, sometimes it doesn't.)

[image: With custom animatable font modifier]

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it. However, here are two workarounds.

1. If you toggle the flag `withAnimation` instead of using `.animation` then it works slightly better, like your last example. To pull it together completely, add `.drawingGroup()` too:

```swift
Button {
    withAnimation(.spring(duration: 2, bounce: 0)) {
        big.toggle()
    }
} label: {
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .background(.yellow)
        .font(.system(size: big ? 100 : 20, weight: .bold))
        .drawingGroup()
}
```

[image: Animation]

*EDIT* As you remarked in your comment, this is better than the original animation, but not perfect. And I agree with you, that `.drawingGroup` is normally to be avoided if possible. So here is a second workaround.

2. Use an `Animatable` `ViewModifier` to apply the font change, Like this:

```swift
struct FontModifier: ViewModifier, Animatable {
    private let fontSizeBegin: CGFloat
    private let fontsizeEnd: CGFloat
    private var progress: CGFloat

    init(fontSizeBegin: CGFloat = 20, fontsizeEnd: CGFloat = 100, progress: CGFloat) {
        self.fontSizeBegin = fontSizeBegin
        self.fontsizeEnd = fontsizeEnd
        self.progress = progress
    }

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { progress }
        set { progress = newValue }
    }

    private var font: Font {
        let size = fontSizeBegin + ((fontsizeEnd - fontSizeBegin) * (progress / 100))
        return .system(size: size)
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(font)
            .bold()
    }
}
```

Use it by replacing the `.font` modifier in your original code:

```swift
Button {
    big.toggle()
} label: {
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .background(.yellow)
        .modifier(FontModifier(progress: big ? 100 : 0))
        .animation(.spring(duration: 2, bounce: 0), value: big)
}
```

[image: Animation]

This works quite reliably until you try to interrupt an animation, when it goes back to being out-of-sync. If there was a way to detect when an interruption happens then it might be possible to control it better under these circumstances.

*EDIT2* Just realised, this approach was already included in your OP, so nothing new here (sorry). You said in the OP that it was not behaving consistently. I think it does, as long as you let the animation continue to completion. When you interrupt it, like trying to reverse it before completion, then it turns strange.

Comment: The animation is certainly *better* this way, but if you look closely, text and background animation are still not in sync. For example, the exclamation mark is truncated on the right during the animation. This problem becomes more apparent when you reverse the animation in-flight. I'm also trying to avoid using `drawingGroup()` if possible as it flattens the view's subtree and thus would prevent proper individual animations with more complex (composed) views where you want to achieve the same effect for each of those views.

Comment: @Mischa Answer updated with a second workaround (using an animatable modifier).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer to my question, but a hint to what's going on that might help others.

I experimented a bit more and appended a `.background` modifier after the `.animation` modifier to see if it affects the view's frame in any way. Turns out it does!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var big = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            big.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.system(size: big ? 100 : 20, weight: .bold))
                .background(.yellow) // 
                .animation(.spring(duration: 2, bounce: 0), value: big)
                .background(.pink)   // 
        }
    }
}
```

This is a slowed-down version of what I observed:

[image: Drawing canvas is animating differently]

#### The "Animation Canvas"

The animation modifier seems to create "a canvas for itself" that is initially and at the end of the animation identical to the child view it's attached to. However, this canvas (i.e. its frame) is not animated according to the animation curve you specify as a parameter. It seems to always animate using the `.default` animation, not matter what.

This creates a delta between the "animation drawing canvas" frame (pink) and the actual (child) content frame (yellow) as they are animated with different timing curves. Within the drawing canvas, the animated content is anchored with its upper left corner, causing the observed weird bouncing behavior.

#### A Possible Fix

One way to fix this is to offer the full available space to the `.animation` modifier with a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` modifier. This way, the entire space is used as an animation canvas which doesn't change in size.

[image: Fixed behavior inside a full frame]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var big = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            big.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.system(size: big ? 100 : 20, weight: .bold))
                .background(.yellow)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // ⬅️
                .animation(.spring(duration: 2, bounce: 0), value: big)
                .background(.pink)
        }
    }
}
```

The yellow background and the text are still not 100% in sync as one of the two animations probably starts a split second after the other, but I find that acceptable as nothing is truncated.

#### SwiftUI Bug?

It's not a perfect solution and I would expect the yellow and the pink frames to be exactly aligned and in sync. I would even go as far as to say that this is a SwiftUI bug. However, it's the best I could come up with and hopefully helps a few folks running into the same issue.

---

PS: For the sake of completeness, here's the proof that the "animation canvas" is always animated with the same timing curve. This is how it looks when I use an animation duration of 0.2 (which is fast than the default timing curve).

[image: Animation faster than default]

You see that in this case the animation canvas is "lagging behind".